# How to get Top 25 records order by createdon using SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql

I have two tables Like updatetext and users I want to top distinct records from updatetext.. Table User having unique records realated to user information and updatetext having multiple updatetext records... I want to get top latest update from updatetext table.. How I can get?

```
Users Table
1) userid
2) username
3) password
4) createdon

UpdateText Table
1) updatetextID
2) userid
3) updateScrap
4) createdon
3) location
```

**UpdateText**

```
updatetextID    userid  updateScrap     Createdon
     11      535     yes good test      2/23/2011 9:59
     12      540    udpate sample       2/23/2011 9:58
     13       44    Absas               2/22/2011 12:30
     14       20    test text 123       2/22/2011 12:24
     15      540    hi how are you?     2/22/2011 12:00
     16      535    Hi r u there?       2/22/2011 12:30
     17      540    welcome back        2/22/2011 10:23
```

**User**

```
userid  username    password    
535 abhi        
540 shankar     
44  dhaval      
20  john
```

I want to get top createdon records from UpdateText Table and
get username and password from Users table..
Please help me.

Comment: Can you give sample data please? Your comment to the answer so far makes no sense. Do you mean "top 25 per user" or "top 25, latest per user"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  TOP 25 
        ut.*
        ,u.username
        ,u.password
FROM    [UpdateText] ut
JOIN    Users u ON  ut.userid = u.userid
JOIN    (   SELECT  MAX(ut2.createdon) as maxcreatedon
                    ,ut2.userid
            FROM    [UpdateText] ut2
            GROUP BY ut2.userid
        ) x ON x.maxcreatedon = ut.createdon
            AND x.userid = ut.userid
ORDER BY ut.createdon DESC
```

Maybe you are searching for something like this?

Comment: Below answer also works. it used CTE , Is it good way to optimize sql query?

Answer (score 1):

This is top 25, latest update per user. I'm guessing this is what you really mean

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT
     *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY createdon) AS RankNum
  FROM
     [UpdateText]
)
SELECT TOP 25
   *
FROM
   CTE 
   JOIN
   Users U ON CTE.userid  = U.userid 
WHERE
   RankNum = 1
ORDER BY
   CTE.createdon
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @gbn solution is good. I liked it... Thanks yaar

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand completely, but try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM UpdateText 
   INNER JOIN Users ON UpdateText.userid = Users.userid
ORDER BY UpdateText.createdon DESC LIMIT 25
```

Comment: But I Getting multiple userId when I execute query.. In my updatetext table there are many update of users.. reply me.